# How to add a field to a dbf file?

Tags: python, dbf

I have something about like this:

```
from dbfpy import dbf
import random

db = dbf.Dbf('DMWWGS84/DMAWGS84.dbf',new=False)
db.addField(("Data","D"))
for record in db:
    print record
    record["Data"]=random.random()
db.close()
```

But it complains:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge_csv.py", line 5, in <module>
    db.addField(("Data","D"))
  File "/Users/alex/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbfpy/dbf.py", line 246, in addField
    raise TypeError("At least one record was added, "
TypeError: At least one record was added, structure can't be changed
```

What record is it talking about? Is this a good way to do this?

Comment: The record that's already in it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams:  How can a record that's already in it be "added"?  If you are correct then that's a terrible error message.

Comment: @EthanFurman: Yeah, probably not the world's best wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use my [dbf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) library instead:

> pip install dbf

(you may need to `pip install enum34` first)

and then the commands:

```
# lightly tested

import dbf
import random

db = dbf.Table('whatever.dbf')
with db:
    db.add_fields('data N(12,7)')
    for record in db:
        dbf.write(record, data=random.random())
```

**NB**:  Writing random numbers to a date field will *not* work well.

Comment: @BigBoy1337: fixed last sentence (turns out "not" can be a very important word! ;)

Comment: Got this Error: _init__.py", line 5896, in add_fields
    raise FieldSpecError(exc.message + ' (%s:%s)' % (meta.filename, name)).from_exc(None)
dbf.FieldSpecError: Format for Character field creation is 'C(n)', not 'C (20) BINARY NULL SYSTEM' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\user_backup.dbf:ID)_

Comment: @rubStackOverflow: Please ask a new question (and make sure you have the latest version of `dbf`).

Answer (score -1):

There´s a bug in this answer, you should open the file before use it:

```
import dbf
import random

db = dbf.Table('whatever.dbf')
db.open()
with db:
    db.add_fields('data N(12,7)')
    for record in db:
        dbf.write(record, data=random.random())
```

Comment: `dbf.Table` can act as a context manager, and opens and closes the file automatically when used that way.